# Display IOException into Primefaces Messages

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to display IOException into Primefaces messages but the text is not formated properly
[image]

In my code I catch the exception:

```
} catch (Exception ex) {
      System.out.println(ex);
      msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, null,ex.toString());
      facesGetCurrentInstance(msg);
}
```

Then add the message:

```
public void facesGetCurrentInstance(FacesMessage msg) {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
 }
```

In the XHTML I am using growl to display the message

```
<p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" sticky="true" autoUpdate="true"   />
```

Thus far everything works, but I am having an issue with how the message is getting displayed. I am assuming this because I am using .toString. So, is there another way to do this?

Comment: Did you try to display Any other Long string Without whitespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,exception.getMessage());
```